# post save signal only when update called

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

hello i have two models and a post_save signal, but my signal only when object is updated is work and when i create a new object it not work

***my code :***

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    classroom = models.ForeignKey('Class', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_present = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    present_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.username


class Class(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['quantity', 'course']


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.quantity} / {self.course}'


@receiver(post_save, sender=Class)
def create_attendance(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for student in instance.students.all():
        try:
            Attendance.objects.get(classroom=instance, student=student)
        except Attendance.DoesNotExist:
            Attendance.objects.create(classroom=instance, student=student)
```

Comment: At the moment you *create* the instance, the `instance.students` is *not* populated (yet). This is because it first needs to create a record with a primary key, to then use it for the *junction* table.

Comment: but i use post_save signal it means call after create obj

Comment: first the object is saved, and then the form will save the m2m relation, so these items are "linked" *after* the `post_save` signals have fired.

Comment: see [my article](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html) about all problems with using signals. Only in very *rare* circumstances, these are a goo idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you *create* the instance, the `instance.students` is *not* populated (yet) and thus *empty*, this means that `for student in instance.students.all()` will enumerate over an empty collection, and thus not enumerate *at all*.

This is because it first needs to create a record with a primary key, to then use it for the *junction* table, which is one of the (many) reasons why using signals is often *not* a good idea.

It might be better to work with an [**`m2m_changed`** signal [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed), and thus implement this like:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Class.students.through)
def create_attendance(sender, instance, action, pk_set=None, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add':
        for pk in pk_set:
            Attendance.objects.get_or_create(classroom=instance, student_id=pk)
```

The modeling however looks a bit odd. Why not make `Attendance` the [*through model* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) of you `ManyToManyField`? That way Django will create `Attendance` records, that you then can update accordingly.

Comment: thanks brother it work but in your code is two problem : 1.(pk set=None) must be before **kwargs
 2.(sender=sender=Class.students.through) must be (sender=Class.students.through)
please solve they for the others.
Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

There is a created argument in post_save signal which is **True** when the instance is created and **False** when the instance is not created(updated).

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Class)
def create_attendance(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:  
        for student in instance.students.all():
            try:
                Attendance.objects.get(classroom=instance, student=student)
            except Attendance.DoesNotExist:
                Attendance.objects.create(classroom=instance, student=student)
```

Comment: This will not change anything, since the signal *is* triggered, but at that moment `instance.students.all()` will be empty.

Comment: the signal is triggered on `obj.save()`. whether it's created or updated, and if class has any students then student won't be empty. so why `instance.students.all()` is empty

Comment: when you *create* an object, it will *first* run `obj.save()` *before* it can populate the m2m relation. This is because we need a *primary key* to use in the junction table. If I thus, for example through some form, create a `Class` with ten students, then first it will create the `Class` recod, then fire the `post_save` signal, and then it will populate the m2m relation with the forms `save_m2m` method.